# Strict Autocomplete JComboBox with Search

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, jcombobox

I am looking for a solution where I want to select items automatically in `JComboBox` based on typing. I am using the following code:

```
package autocompletion;

/**
*
* @author admin
*/
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.ComboBoxEditor;
import javax.swing.ComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;

public class AutoCompletion extends PlainDocument {

JComboBox comboBox;
ComboBoxModel model;
JTextComponent editor;
// flag to indicate if setSelectedItem has been called
// subsequent calls to remove/insertString should be ignored
boolean selecting=false;
boolean hidePopupOnFocusLoss;
boolean hitBackspace=false;
boolean hitBackspaceOnSelection;

KeyListener editorKeyListener;
FocusListener editorFocusListener;

public AutoCompletion(final JComboBox comboBox) {
    this.comboBox = comboBox;
    model = comboBox.getModel();
    editor = (JTextComponent) comboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
    editor.setDocument(this);
    comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (!selecting) highlightCompletedText(0);
        }
    });
    editor.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (comboBox.isDisplayable()) comboBox.setPopupVisible(true);
        }
    });
    // Bug 5100422 on Java 1.5: Editable JComboBox won't hide popup when tabbing out
    hidePopupOnFocusLoss=System.getProperty("java.version").startsWith("1.5");
    // Highlight whole text when gaining focus
    editor.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            highlightCompletedText(0);
        }
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            // Workaround for Bug 5100422 - Hide Popup on focus loss
            if (hidePopupOnFocusLoss) comboBox.setPopupVisible(false);
        }
    });
    // Handle initially selected object
    Object selected = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
    if (selected!=null) setText(selected.toString());
    highlightCompletedText(0);
}

public static void enable(JComboBox comboBox) {
    // has to be editable
    comboBox.setEditable(true);
    // change the editor's document
    new AutoCompletion(comboBox);
}

void configureEditor(ComboBoxEditor newEditor) {
    if (editor != null) {
        editor.removeKeyListener(editorKeyListener);
        editor.removeFocusListener(editorFocusListener);
    }

    if (newEditor != null) {
        editor = (JTextComponent) newEditor.getEditorComponent();
        editor.addKeyListener(editorKeyListener);
        editor.addFocusListener(editorFocusListener);
        editor.setDocument(this);
    }
}

 public void remove(int offs, int len) throws BadLocationException {
    // return immediately when selecting an item
    if (selecting) return;
    //System.out.println("remove " + len + " at " + offs);
    super.remove(offs, len);
}

public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {
    // return immediately when selecting an item
    if (selecting) return;
    // insert the string into the document
    super.insertString(offs, str, a);
    // lookup and select a matching item
    Object item = lookupItem(getText(0, getLength()));
    if (item != null) {
        setSelectedItem(item);
    } else {
        // keep old item selected if there is no match
        item = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
        // imitate no insert (later on offs will be incremented by str.length(): selection won't move forward)
        offs = offs-str.length();
        // provide feedback to the user that his input has been received but can not be accepted
        comboBox.getToolkit().beep(); // when available use: UIManager.getLookAndFeel().provideErrorFeedback(comboBox);
    }
    setText(item.toString());
    // select the completed part
    highlightCompletedText(offs+str.length());
}

private void setText(String text) {
    try {
        // remove all text and insert the completed string
        super.remove(0, getLength());
        super.insertString(0, text, null);
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.toString());
    }
}


private void highlightCompletedText(int start) {
    editor.setCaretPosition(getLength());
    editor.moveCaretPosition(start);
}

private void setSelectedItem(Object item) {
    selecting = true;
    model.setSelectedItem(item);
    selecting = false;
}

private Object lookupItem(String pattern) {
    Object selectedItem = model.getSelectedItem();
    // only search for a different item if the currently selected does not match
    if (selectedItem != null && startsWithIgnoreCase(selectedItem.toString(), pattern)) {
        return selectedItem;
    } else {
        // iterate over all items
        for (int i=0, n=model.getSize(); i < n; i++) {
            Object currentItem = model.getElementAt(i);
            // current item starts with the pattern?
            if (currentItem != null && startsWithIgnoreCase(currentItem.toString(), pattern)) {
                return currentItem;
            }
        }
    }
    // no item starts with the pattern => return null
    return null;
}

// checks if str1 starts with str2 - ignores case
private boolean startsWithIgnoreCase(String str1, String str2) {
    return str1.toUpperCase().startsWith(str2.toUpperCase());
}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    // the combo box (add/modify items if you like to)
    final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(new Object[] {"Ester", "Jordi", "Jordina", "Jorge", "Sergi"});
    enable(comboBox);

    // create and show a window containing the combo box
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    frame.getContentPane().add(comboBox);
    frame.pack(); frame.setVisible(true);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Auto-selection is working fine when I type the first letter of an item. But when I try to type from the middle of the item, i.e. if I type *"ter"*, it should auto-select *"Ester"*.

Please let me know the solution.

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It's hard to help you if all you provide is 188 lines of code and zero to no comments or documentation to help someone who would like to answer your question. If this is too much effort for you to put in, feel free to read this [open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: @BlkPengu I don't know where I should edit/change the code to fulfill my requirement.

Comment: delete all code that is circumstantial (like method calls that are not important for the JComboBox issue) or your main (it' too obvious to add anything to the issue. It's just assumed that you have a main). Highlight the part that is not working and explain why you think it's not working. Add comments to your code if it can't be condensed further.

**Edit:** I'm aware this requires careful thinking about what's relevant and what isn't. However this will help you understand better and help anyone who is trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the '[Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)' between the typed word and the words in your list. The word with the lowest *Levenshtein distance* is the most probable match (although note there may be several close matches, so you'll need to work out how you handle those).

I would start by having two lists rather than just one: the display list, and the list for matching. The list for matching would be made entirely lowercase to make searching easier. From there, try studying the following class for how to compare two words: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/jacoco/org.apache.commons.text.similarity/LevenshteinDistance.java.html